# Boton Flat en Android Material Design

Tags: android

Por defecto cuando se crea un botón en Android Studio, su aspecto hereda el diseño de Material Design, en la guía de estilo de Material Design, habla de botones `Flat, Raised` Raised creo que es el por defecto

**Botón Flat**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Botón Raised**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Resumen de lo que pregunto*

- Veo que el raised le añaden ese efecto de `glow` para elevarlo, como
  se le asigna?
- ¿Cómo se especifica que sea estilo como flat button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Resultado final**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Debes añadir primeramente la librería de soporte.

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X'
}
```

**Respuesta para `Raised Button.`**

> Defines tu propio estilo.

```
<style name="MiRaisedBoton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#00BCD4</item>
</style>
```

> Aplicas el estilo.

```
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RAISED BUTTON"
    android:theme="@style/MiRaisedBoton"/>
```

**Respuesta para `Raised Button con elevación` (API +19)**

> Defines tu propia animación.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                        android:valueTo="@dimen/button_pressed_z_material"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                        android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                        android:valueTo="0"
                        android:startDelay="@integer/button_pressed_animation_delay"
                        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:duration="0"
                        android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                        android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
```

> Asignas la animación.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RAISED BUTTON ELEVADO"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/mi_animacion"/>
```

**Respuesta para `Flat Button.`**

> Asignas el estilo Borderless.

```
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FLAT BUTTON"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

> En caso de querer definir tu propio estilo.

```
<style name="MiFlatBoton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <!-- tus propios cambios -->
</style>
```

> Y tras definir tu propio estilo por supuesto indicarlo para usarlo.

```
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FLAT BUTTON"
    android:theme="@style/MiFlatBoton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

Más información: [ENLACE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle)

Comment: Gracias, muy completo la respuesta

Comment: +1 muy buena explicación.

Comment: Añado la elevación que ya me informé, no es necesario utilizar CardView como comenté anteriormente, simplemente con animaciones se logra hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es usar los estilos de la librería de compatibilidad, sobre un `Button` o `AppCompatButton`

### Flat Button

Para botones solo texto, boton text, flat button:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Definir el estilo en: `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

**Colorido** El color del texto sera el que este definido en `colorAccent` del tema.

Definir el estilo en: `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

#### Personalización

Para la personalización podemos definir un estilo propio, para así cambiar el color del texto, color onda al pulsar, solo en aquellos botones que lo deseamos.

El color del texto lo cambiamos en `<item name="colorAccent">` y el color de la onda expansiva en `<item name="colorControlHighlight">`

**Estilo PrimaryFlatButton**

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

para usarlo en el botón usar `android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonAwesome3"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text=" Button" />
```